# Justify text in visual block

Tags: vim, alignment, block, text-alignment

Is there a way in Vim to justify text within a Visual Block?

p.e. a partial example of my file:

```
text text  |5  sm 23  |
text  text |1274 hc a4|
text text  | 33 rnd bc|
 text text | 28 yz 22 |
text text  |9808 yz 56|
```

expected output:

```
text text   5   sm  23
text  text  1274 hc a4
text text   33  rnd bc
 text text  28  yz  22
text text   9808 yz 56
```

I enabled virtualedit: `:set virtualedit=all`.
I added a column with spaces (at the right `|` in my example) in order to create two spaces after "23" and 1 space after "22".
Then I selected the visual block and executed the command `:'<,'>ce`
without the expected output.

Comment: you have to program for it. btw, from my understanding, this is not "center",  you want your text to be filled maximal in visual range. And you want to make change to the spaces inner your line of text. `:center` doesn't touch those spaces. So you have to write your own function

Comment: You're right, I mean Justify. I'm gonna change it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is commonly called *justify* (to left and right margins by adding inner whitespace); whereas *center* adds whitespace to left and right to have equal amounts.

There are two plugins for justifying *entire lines*:

- `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/justify.vim` ships with Vim
- [Justify plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=177) provides a simple implementation

As you want this applied to a *blockwise selection*, you have to delete the blockwise selection, put them to separate lines / a scratch buffer, justify that (to the original width of the selection), then yank back and insert as a block again. (For those, my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) provides handy `glp` and `gbp` mappings.) Depending on how often you need this, either apply this manually, or try to automate via a custom mapping.

Comment: Hello Ingo, Thanks for answering. I installed the Justify plugin but it did not exactly what I wanted. It doesn't expand the text to the left, it only expands the text to the right. Maybe I have to write it myself as Kent wrote in his comment. Count spaces between words on a line, put them in a List with a counter and divide them by the counter and put them back in text, or something like that.

Comment: You could fix that by `:left`-aligning the text (already on separate lines) first. I agree, if you need a fully automated solution that does exactly what you want, there's no way around implementing it yourself, maybe using the plugin(s) for ideas.